# Creating hosted network with netsh when having to select the adapter

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, netsh

I'm on Win7. I usually create a hosted network by creating then executing a process that runs `netsh wlan hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=MYSSID key=MYPASSWORD keyusage=temporary`. So far, no problem.

But now I have computers with the internal WiFi adapter and one or more external USB WiFi adapter. How can I select the adapter used to bridge with the MiniPort since there is no such option in the `netsh wlan...` command? I am a beginner with `netsh`.

Can it be done programmatically? (I develop in C++ native and CLI) Or only from command line?